# application doesn't work on macos server

Tags: cocoa

I was try to run my working application on macos server, but application show error - can't open programm bcs it's doesn't support this type of mac computer.
Any suggest? probably i have to change something in target?

${MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}

MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6

System Software Overview:

System Version:   Mac OS X Server 10.6.6 (10J567)
  Server Configuration: Advanced
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 10.6.0

everything looks good.

ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT)

i don't understand, which exact difference have must be for those configurations

ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES was configured and using 32-bit configuration is working fine.
i was change it. to NO and everything start working.
But why server don't support 64bit target architecture?

**SOLUTION 2**
delete from valid architectures all and leave i386 and x86_64.
In this case application working well on server.

Answer (score 2):

Along with version, you can see that if you compile your application to the wrong architecture. In "Build Settings" for you application make sure you have the correct architecture selected.

Comment: I would also check "Valid Architecture -> i386, x86_64", "Supported Platforms -> macosx"

Comment: In the main view (Project Navigator), select you application at the top, then under "Project" select your application again, then build settings.

Comment: @Staros VALID_ARCHS = i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64
looks good but still not working well